# Reverse engineer an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, reverse-engineering

I have an algorithm that uses time, and other variables to create keys that are 30 characters in length.

The FULL results look like this: d58fj27sdn2348j43dsh2376scnxcs

Because it uses time, and other variables, it will always change.

All you see is the first 6: d58fj2

So basically, if you monitor my results, each time you would see different once, and only the first 6:

d58fj2
kfd834
n367c6
9vh364
vc822c
c8u23n
df8m23
jmsd83

QUESTION: Would you ever be able to reverse engineer and figure out the algorithm calculating them? REMEMBER, you NEVER see the full result, just the first 6 digits out of 30.

QUESTION 2: To those saying it's possible, how many keys would you need in order to do that? (And I still mean, just the first 6 digits out of the 30)

Thanks

Comment: Well, reverse engineering is reimplementing an algorithm from the results of that algorithm. As you can never see the result, you can't reverse engineer it. Would you be able to reverse engineer it if you only see first 0 digits?

Comment: Yes, given enough time to bruteforce it or create a decent rainbow table...

What are you actually asking here? If it's possible to reverse engineer it? Yes it is. Will the reverse-engineered solution be production-ready and instantly reusable in other projects? No it would not.

Comment: Maybe, it depends on whether there is some internal structure that has some polynomial relation to the first 6 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. To those saying it's possible, how many keys would you need in order to do that? (And I still mean, just the first 6 digits out of the 30)

Comment: It may be possible to predict the 6 first letters, but as we know nothing about the structure of the algorithm, it seems to be impossible to predict the rest. If you can get your hands on the code, (even if it is binary), you could disassamble / discompile it.

Comment: Impossible task. Just imagine that the visible part be generated by algorithm #1, the remainder using algo #2, the result being concatenated. If both algorithms are not tied to each other, there'll be no way to reverse-engineer algo #2, and even if they were you'd have no clue in which way they were related.

Comment: It's theoretically possible to reverse engineer this if there is some (relatively easy) internal structure. Prepare to work on it your whole life without a guarantee that you'd be successful at the end of it.

Comment: Reverse engineering is all about making the right assumptions. If I *assume* that I'm only seeing the first 6 characters of a longer value, and I'm making the right assumptions about how that longer value is being created, **of course** I can reverse-engineer it. All it depends on is how obscure your algorithm is and how good my guesses are.

Comment: "Obscurity is not security". Never was, and never will be....

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to risk the downvotes, but somehow this quickly started smelling like school (home)work.

The question itself - "Is this reverse-engineerable? REMBER, you never see the full result" is suspicious enough; if you can see the full result, so can I. Whether you store it locally so i can take my time inspecting it, or whether it goes thru the wire so i have to hunt it down is another matter - having to use wireshark or not, I can still see what's being transmitted to and from the app.

Remember, at some point WEP used to be "unbreakable" while now alot of lowend laptops can crack them easily.

The second question however - "how many samples would you need to see to figure it out" sounds like one of those dumb impractical teacher questions. Some people guess their friends' passwords on first try, some take a few weeks... The number of tries, unfortunatelly, isn't the deciding factor in reverse-engineering. Only having the time to try them all is; which is why people use expensive locks on their doors - because they're not unbreakable, but because it takes more than a few seconds to break them which increases the chances that the neighbours will see suspicious activity.

But asking the crowd "how many keys would you need to see to crack this algorithm you know nothing about" leads nowhere, as it's merely a defensive move that does not provide any guarantees; the author of the algorithm very well knows how many samples one needs to break it using statistical analysis. (in case of WEP, that's anywhere between 5000 - 50000 - 200000 IVs). Some passwords break down with 5k, some hardly breaking with 200k...

Answering your questions in more detail with academic proof requires more info from your side; much more than the ambiguous "can you do it, and if yes, how long would it take?" question which is what it currently is.

Comment: Spot on. `you never see the full result` is just wishful thinking with real security issues.